# want to extend auth_user model in django by adding two fields

Tags: django

in django,i want to extend the auth_user model and adding the 2 fields.one is created_user which will display the date and time when user created something and other is modified_user which will display the date n time when modification is done..

is it possible by migration?? 
i ve tried dis code..

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, UserManager

class CustomUser(User):
    created_user= models.DateTimeField("date and time when created")
    modified_user=models.DateTimeField("date and time when modified")

    objects= UserManager()
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reading [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model) on creating your own custom user model.

In your particular case, the easiest thing would probably be to subclass `AbstractUser` and add your fields as above.

> If you’re entirely happy with Django’s User model and you just want to add some additional profile information, you can simply subclass django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser and add your custom profile fields. This class provides the full implementation of the default User as an abstract model.